# Variable number of sub seconds in json encoded time

Tags: json, go, time, go-gorm

So I have numerous structs which extend the gorm Model meaning they have createdAt, updatedAt and deletedAt time.Time fields. When I go to marshal these into JSON, the formats of the dates I receive vary. The proper RFC3339 timestamps it should produce look like:

2016-04-18T00:03:20Z

However, I am only getting dates formatted this way about 20% of the time. The remainder of the timestamps have a variable number of subseconds. I have received the following formats:

2016-04-18T05:51:11.54772087Z

2016-04-18T05:51:11.543835101Z

2016-04-18T05:53:20.1674444Z

Is there any way I can coerce Go into to giving me consistent timestamps? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not RFC3339, its RFC3339Nano, see this http://play.golang.org/p/7oJ_-7FmB- (run it localy, the time in playground is limited) and can you show when you get the first one and when the others?

Comment: @fzerorubigd I'm getting 
2016-04-18T18:35:39-04:00
2016-04-18T18:35:39.524444112-04:00
When I run that locally. Neither of those matches the schema of the dates i'm getting from Go's json parser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to control the output, is writing your own type. say `type MyTime time.Time` and implement [Marshaller](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [Unmarshaller](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) for it with your formatting. see [time.MarshalJSON](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.MarshalJSON) and [time.UnmarshalJSON](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnmarshalJSON) for hint. if you need this in a database column, implement the `Scanner` and `Valuer` on that too ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688008/couldt-convert-nil-into-type/36691455#36691455)). for other Marshaller/Unmarshaller you need to implement their interfaces (for example yaml/gob/...)